# Javascript Object displaying undefined for some properties

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Node.js. Displaying the data (let's call location) it will show 6 properties, but printing the specific property displays undefined.

Here is the actual data :

```
{
    _id: 5552e591 ce245dd4f38e51d3,
    boundary: {
        type: 'Polygon',
        coordinates: [
            [Object]
        ]
    },
    map_reg_name: 'Cordillera Administrative Region (CAR)',
    loc_type_desc: 'Region',
    boundary_lowres: {
        coordinates: [
            [Object]
        ],
        type: 'Polygon'
    },
    coordinates: []
}
```

Printing all other properties except **boundary_lowres** is working.

Upon debugging, I tried assigning value to `location.boundary_lowres` to simple `'Hi'`. Then printing location and `location.boundary_lowres` displayed different values. `location` is still printing the old value while `location.boundary_lowres` is now `'Hi'`

Comment: Can you show how are you printing?

Comment: Can you show your html

Comment: Hi Zee, I'm using console.log(location) and console.log(location.boundary_lowres). Also I'm sending the data as a web service reply and returning the object location will display boundary_lowres but returning only boundary_lowres will just be an empty object.

Comment: empty object `{}` or `undefined`? You say undefined in the question and empty object in your comment...

Comment: `undefined` in the console but node is converting the undefined object to `{}` when returning the data in the web service.

Comment: if it is `undefined`, I'm guessing you either miss-typed the field `boundary_lowres` or (if you are retrieving the data from a database) you did not include the field in the select query...

Comment: Are you using any java-script template engion?what?